# How to deserialize this YAML in struct with serde_yaml

Tags: rust, yaml

I have this YAML format:

```yaml
  - G1: "Test"
    supportedBy: [Sn1]
  - Sn1: "Lala"
```

I want to parse it into a struct with a similar structure like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct Node {
    supported_by : Option<Vec<String>>
}
```

The problem I face is that the `G1`, `Sn1`, `"Test"` and `"Lala"` can be almost arbitrary text.

One unsatisfying solution I found is using:

```rust
let deser: Vec<Mapping> = serde_yaml::from_str(&test_yaml)?;
```

I was more thinking about something like this:

```rust
let deser: Vec<BTreeMap<String,Node>> = serde_yaml::from_str(&test_yaml)?;
```

However, this does not capture the `"Test"` and `"Lala"`.

I can also modify the YAML structure, but from what I see this is the shortest way to represent the data I would need. The YAML is intended to be manually written.

Is there a way to adapt the `Node` struct to better represent the data?
Any suggestions on how to parse in that YAML structure would be very much appreciated.

Here is the current complete code:

```rust
use indoc::indoc;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use serde_yaml::Mapping;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct Node {
    supported_by : Option<Vec<String>>,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), serde_yaml::Error> {
    let test_yaml = indoc! {"
            ---
            - G1: \"Test\"
              supportedBy: [Sn1]
            - Sn1: \"Lala\"
            "};

    let deser: Vec<Mapping> = serde_yaml::from_str(&test_yaml)?;
    println!("{:?}", deser);
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: can you make your question more unclear please ?

Comment: Sorry, I am aware that the question is quite vague, since I am not sure how a solution could look like. Each list item should be represented by a structure. However, I have no clue how to cover the initial key, value pair in the Rust struct.

Comment: first include at least both example to show what you mean by "The problem I face is that the G1, Sn1, "Test" and "Lala" can be almost arbitrary text.", than include all code you use to parse this using raw rust string like `r###"` and then what the hell there is a `in_context_of ` that pop from nowhere. And finally a HS thing serde_yaml sux very hard is bugged etc if you control the format advice use toml.

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks for the feedback. I removed the `in_context_of` and added the complete code. I am looking for a struct that has the initial key (e.g. `G1`), value (e.g. `"Text"`) as e.g. two members or as a BTreeMap of String, Node...

Comment: @Stargateur could you please elaborate on the statement serde_yaml is bugged? The issues on GitHub don't look too serious or too many.

Comment: I don't know why people don't report bug but each time I run into serde_yaml, message error are shit, sometime if a field is missing the program abort, etc. Use hjson or toml for config file not yamlshit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is associated a `HashMap` for example, and [`#[serde(flatten)]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#flatten) (a direct application of [Capture additional fields](https://serde.rs/attr-flatten.html#capture-additional-fields)):

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct Node {
    supported_by : Option<Vec<String>>,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    extras: HashMap<String, String>,
}

fn main() -> Result<(), serde_yaml::Error> {
    let test_yaml = r#"---
- G1: "Test"
  supportedBy: [Sn1]
- Sn1: "Lala"
"#;

    let deser: Vec<Node> = serde_yaml::from_str(&test_yaml)?;
    println!("{:#?}", deser);
    Ok(())
}
```

One could use `serde_yaml::Value;` in place of string in `extras: HashMap<String, Value>,` to allow anything instead of just `String`.